# Upgrading Angular CLI to the latest version?

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

I started a new angular project, this works fine for me when I use:

```
npm start
```

However I'm trying to use:

```
ng serve
```

Then /I tryed this:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

However I'm getting this error, even when I run the command:

```
ng --version


An invalid configuration file was found ['/home/edson/.angular.json']. Please delete the file before running the command.
```

Someone knows why it's happening ?

Comment: Have you tried deleting or renaming `~/.angular.json`?

Comment: I can't find this file, this file doesn't exist

Comment: you first clear cache by running 'npm cache clear --force'. Then try npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest. Then try npm install

Comment: Still the same error, I just can run with using npm start